# Modification timestamp for documents in a BaseX database

Tags: gnu-make, basex

I have a gnu make system, and would like to trigger rules based on updates to documents in a BaseX XML database. In other words, something like `archive(member)` can be used in gnu make to refer to a member of an archive, I would like to use `db(foo.xml)`. Or, since that's probably not possible, some workaround involving creating dummy files with the correct timestamps, but I can't even figure out how to retrieve the modification date from a document in a BaseX database.

Comment: On the BaseX mailing list I have been advised there __is__no modification time or timestamp maintained in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking as an answer that BaseX does **not** maintain document modification times.